# Unity: linerenderer and objects disappear when almost out of screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, physics, bounce

Video: https://youtu.be/S8gw0YPrpXE

The objects and the line-renderer disappear. The objects disappear when they are almost out of view and the line-renderer disappears randomly, but only at specific y-locations. How can I fix this? (See included video)

I changed the viewport of camera and I tried to change the clipping port

I expect the problem to be fixed so the objects and the line-renderer won't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your line renderer is too close to your background plane or geometry.

If this is not the problem, you may need to post some more information about your scene setup.

Comment: This didn't work. What information do you want about the scene setup?

Comment: If you pause the game at the moment where the LineRenderer disappears, is the GameObject still active? Is your line renderer in world mode or local mode? If world mode, what is the object position in relation to the camera frustum (it might be getting culled)? How far exactly is the geometry from the background? What are the camera near and far plane values? If you rotate your view in the scene view, do you see the linerenderer ?

Comment: The line-renderer is still active when it is invisible. I believe the linerenderer is in local space. The other linerenderer in which is in an empty gameobject somehow does work. The distance between the object and the wall is a little higher than the size of the object. camera settings: near: 0.01 (lowest possible) far:  1000 (highest possible). IMPORTANT: I just found out that the line renderer IS visible in the scene, but not in playmode and the objects only disappear at specific y-values

Comment: I fixed the problem with the linerenderer by changing some settings, but I still have problems with the objects which disappear when they are almost out of view.